# Best way to target all screen DPIs (without tablets)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

My application will contain about 100 images and will only be available for smartphones (no tablets). So I'm thinking about the best way to target all screen DPIs. Now there are two ways:

1. Making all images to Extra High or Extra High DPI
2. Making all images for every single DPI

The first way is of course the faster way and would work with the auto-scale function of Android. The second way is very time-consuming but probably the better way.

What do you recommend in my case?

And if MDP is my baseline size, which size it should be?
Is there a "correct" size for all of my images?

Comment: ? You just have to export the image in different sizes...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target all devices densities (i.e. you have the corresponding filter in the manifest, if your app will be published on Google's Play Store), you should include the resources for all the "regular" densities.

As you pointed out, you can include only the highest-resolution resources, but this means that lower-densities devices will have to scale them down, using system resources (CPU and RAM) and risking random `OutOfMemoryError`s at runtime. Using only lower-resolution resources, on the contrary, will result in a lower visual quality on high-density devices.

As of 2017, the list of densities you should support in a smartphone app is:

- `mdpi` (1x) (optional)
- `hdpi` (1.5x)
- `xhdpi` (2x)
- `xxhdpi` (3x)
- `xxxhdpi` (4x)

This leaves out the `tvdpi` density (which is not a "standard" one, it is 1.33x) and the `ldpi` one, which is very outdated. `mdpi` devices as well have a [very low market share](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), and are mostly tablets. You should take a decision thinking about the type of your app, the average users and their devices and other factors, as the 100 MB APK limit on the Play Store.

Another good approach is to use vectorial drawables, in particular for icons and smaller images. This allow you to have only one file which is rendered perfectly on every screen.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at **Android Asset Studio** and see if it helps:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/